# Replace Default WordPress Logo with the Current Theme Logo in WordPress Login Page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-login

I'm trying to replace the WordPress login logo with the active theme logo. The active theme is using the default "Customizer" options for the logo.

I'm using the following code

```
function my_custom_login_logo() {
echo '<style type="text/css">
h1 a {background-image:url(https://broproud.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/cropped-150-Width-Logo.png) !important; margin:0 auto;}
</style>';
}
add_filter( 'login_head', 'my_custom_login_logo' );
```

I know, I can change the logo, with this code, but how can I display the active theme logo automatically? What kind of function is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try this one

```
function my_custom_login_logo() {
    $logo_url = ( function_exists( 'the_custom_logo' ) && get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' ) ) ? wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' ), 'full' ) : false;
    $logo_url = ( $logo_url ) ? $logo_url[0] : generate_get_option( 'logo' );

    $logo_url = esc_url( apply_filters( 'generate_logo', $logo_url ) );

    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        h1 a {
            background-image:url(<?php echo $logo_url ?>) !important; margin:0 auto;}
    </style>
    <?php
}
add_filter( 'login_head', 'my_custom_login_logo' );
```

Comment: Thank You for the code, but it didn't work for me. I placed it in the functions.php file of my active Child Theme. Just FYI, I'm using GeneratePress & The logo is set under "Site Identity" tab (Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/m65unf).

Comment: Ok. I'm now I'm getting the following error (on the login page). 

Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/m66fq9

Comment: Thank You So Much @sftt It worked. I'm grateful for your help.

For anyone else, looking at this answer.

Here is the CSS code I used for adjusting my logo: 

`.login h1 a {background-size: 200px; padding-left: 100px ; padding-right: 100px ;}`

Answer (score 1):

**First step** is to add an action to the login_enqueue_scripts, this is (as stated above) done by adding a code snippet to the themes function.php.

After that you'll find 2 things:

1. if you have a non-square logo it will become very small
2. if you click on it you'll go to wordpress.org

Both can be easily solved in the same snippet with pure css:

```
<style type="text/css">
  body.login div#login h1 a {
    background-image: url(PATH TO YOUR LOGO);
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: contain;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
</style>
<?php
} add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_login_logo' );
```